# Android NFC max receive buffer size

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to do a large FAST_READ command, but if I attempt to receive too many bytes, I get a tag lost error.  I assume there is some max receive buffer size that android can handle, but I don't see it documented anywhere.   There is a getMaxTransceiveLength method on NfcA, but the documentation states that it represents the maximum number of bytes that can be sent even though the function name would imply that it represents the number of bytes that can be transmitted and received.  Is there a limit on the number of bytes that can be received, and if so how can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I have determined that the maximum receive bytes appears to be the same as the maximum transmit bytes.  getMaxTransceiveLength returns 253, and I can FAST_READ 252 bytes successfully, but as soon as I try to FAST_READ 256 bytes, I get the TagLostException.  It would be nice if the documentation for getMaxTransceiveLength was updated to reflect this.